# How to disable "mark down editing" completely

Tags: website

Please anyone tell me how to disable that thing forever.
I cannot post a long question because all format are messed up and hardly readable, I tried for 10 minutes and ended up save it to a file now.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify, which problem arises from 'mark down editing'? You probably mean 'mark down editing' are the StackExchange sites? If you want to start a new paragraph in your question/answer here, you need to press return twice (= two new lines => new paragraph = new line in the question/answer).

Comment: Have a look at [this help article](http://superuser.com/help/formatting) - it explains how to Markdown.

Comment: If the format is messed up you're not using proper markdown syntax. Check the linked article. It's the format the site uses so you will either have to get used to it or you won't be able to write well formatted questions/answers.

Comment: Thank you, yes I mean StackExchange sites, they not only refuse to recognize single enter as new line, but they also messed up all my number list, and more, just look at this question, I have a "Hello" in the beginning, now it's gone. So there's no way to disable this?